# Changing assembly code while running it is possible?

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to ask you that is it possible to change values in assembly code while run-time is possible?

I got a project to sort given data and show the result of it. And the code seems like this.

```
Input_data : .word 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
Output_data : .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

I already have done swapping and every data is saved in sequential memory space. But, I can't find the way to change code while runtime.
Does he mean to show just memory spaces? Or truly can I change .asm code while running it?

I'm using ARM CPU with Zedboard.

Comment: you can change code while running; usually you have to flush the icache before jumping into this new code.

Comment: The code is just bit values in memory, same as data (at least on Von Neumann computer architecture, like x86 PC, ARM, and most of the currently used computer architectures). So you can surely change the code. But specifics may be tricky, like under modern OS you have to deal with write/executable/read type of access into the memory where you are preparing new code, and the CPU may require extra reset of cache to notice new changes, or it will notice them automatically but for huge performance penalty (x86 CPUs). But self-modify code is generally not used today, because it's tricky.

Comment: And usually you don't need to change code at runtime, 99% of time there exist solution which doesn't require code change, or the code change is localized in single specialized component, like JIT compiler. Back in 1970-1990 the self-modify code was often written by hand to save memory space, because the whole computer had for example 4096 bytes of memory... today my computer has 17179869184 bytes of memory, and such tricks would just make the code lot more harder to write, read and debug, so they are rarely used today.

Comment: asm code does not execute by itself it needs to be assembled into machine code.  yes you can if your program is running in ram.  if in flash it gets much more complicated, sometimes yes...as mentioned if caches or other items are in the wy you need to deal with them to insure the modifications you make to the code make it to the processor in a way you wish.    note it is very rare that you would want/need to do this, one would assume there is another way to solve whatever your problem is.

Comment: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve that you think self modifying code is the solution?